# Rakefile task block arg not working

Tags: ruby, rake, rake-task, rakefile

I have a task in my Rakefile

```
desc "Create a new person."
task :add_person, :name do |t, args|
    sh "echo My name is #{args.name}"
end
```

When I do `$ rake add_person john`

I get:

```
echo My name is 
My name is
rake aborted!
Don't know how to......
```

But I should get:

```
echo My name is john
My name is john
rake aborted!
Don't know how to......
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call it like this:

```
rake add_person[john]
```

or if you're using zsh:

```
rake add_person\[john\]
```

*edit:* response to comment about being able to call it like: rake add_person john

I think you have 2 options.

Use the environment variable method for passing args:

```
desc "Create a new person."
task :add_person do |t, args|
  name = ENV.fetch('NAME')
    sh "echo My name is #{name}"
end
```

then call like this:

```
$ rake add_person NAME=john
```

or, Hack using ARGV (not personally recommended):

```
desc "Create a new person."
task :add_person do
  name = ARGV.last
  sh "echo My name is #{name}"
  # Task does nothing
  task name.to_sym do ; end
end
```

then use like this:

```
$rake add_person john
```

personally I'd just use it as in intended though.

Comment: This works. Is there a way to call it like `rake add_person john`? It just looks more elegant that way.

Comment: Added an example of how to do that in my answer, but personally I'd use it as intended.

Comment: Thanks. I just wanted to know. Will use as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Update the task

```
task :add_person, [:name] => :environment do |_t, args|
  puts "My name is #{args[:name]}"
end
```

and run

```
rake add_person['john']
```